# Significance of ".WORLD" on end of Oracle connection

Tags: oracle, connections, tnsnames, sqlnet

What is the significance of having ".WORLD" on the end of an Oracle connection name?  I've found things to still connect without that suffix.  I've also noticed that both the client tnsnames.ora file and the server tnsnames.ora file must both have this suffix (or none at all) in order to communicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.WORLD is a type of domain. You need it in *tnsnames.ora* if this is configured in your *sqlnet.ora* file (*names.default_domain* parameter). If this is not present in *sqlnet.ora* and you have it in *tnsnames.ora*, you have to append it manually. [Sqlnet.ora](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Sqlnet.ora#names.default_domain)

> The value of this parameter is appended to the net service name if the net service name doesn't already have a domain.

The .WORLD isn't needed at all if *names.default_domain* isn't set. In order to get the client working, just make sure the *tnsnames.ora* file on the server (in the network/admin folder) matches the *tnsnames.ora* file on the client (in the client network/admin folder).